# find a row that has a string that contains a certain string, then take the row on top, the strong row and row under and move it to a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

So i have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I want to search though the first column for every time i see `nl.audio` take the row on top, take the nl.audio row and the row right under it and move them to a new column so it looks like this:
[image]

not sure how to go about doing this.

the table comes from trying to get nested json values into a dataframe. like this

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)


files <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".json", all.files=FALSE,
           full.names=FALSE)

data <- fromJSON(files[1])


dat2 <- unlist(data$translation_map)
dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat2)
```

dput:

```
structure(list(dat2 = c("Iraat.", 
" _1645805605.mp3", 
"Ie.", "wn", "", "Wdis.", 
"ewdewf.mp3", 
"wedew.", "[k]ws.[/k]", 
" _1645805740.mp3", 
"edwedwedw.", "Ik ewwewe[/k].", 
"we45805760.mp3", 
"I h89.", "ewd3n", "", "ad23dt", "", 
"Ik d2. ", "I d2d3.", 
"Ha3d3d/k] 20.", "H3d20.", 
"id3n", "", "straat")), row.names = c("str-5e854867d9c6.nl.value", 
"str_f15f7751-227dc6.nl.audio", "str_f15f7751.en.value", 
"str.nl.value", "str_172a516ca.en.value", 
"str_4567f686.nl.value", "str_4.nl.audio", 
"stcb0ca14.en.value", "str_622f99395.nl.value", 
"str_622f9395.nl.audio", "str_622f90de9395.en.value", 
"str_f25afe16.nl.value", "str_f2fad09045afe16.nl.audio", 
"str_f2fad89045afe16.en.value", "s9e844c432e80.nl.value", 
"str_b0c1b42e80.en.value", "str_e6d847f3-60b7-.nl.value", 
"str_.en.value", "str_b61f9404-.nl.value", 
"str_ b.en.value", "str_76e28ea6.nl.value", 
"str-61a1b83bf1ba.en.value", "str_6280d5a49c42a24.nl.value", 
"str5-0d5a49c42a24.en.value", "str_5e6b2202e748.nl.value"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you update with the `dput` of the example so that it can be copied for testing

Comment: If you `dput` the data I'll solve it

Comment: @geoff i posted a dput. this will get reused for other dataframes with the same structure but a random number of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(,str_squish)) %>% 
  mutate(A = ifelse(str_detect(V1, 'nl.audio'), lag(V2), NA_character_),
        # B = str_extract(V2, '\\d+.mp3'),
         B = str_extract(V2, '.*.mp3$'),
         C = ifelse(str_detect(V1, 'nl.audio'), lead(V2), NA_character_),
        .keep= "unused") %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
         A              B          C
2 nstraat. 1645805605.mp3 constraat.
7 tihdhis.  645805622.mp3       use.
```

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("str_f15d9c6.nl.value", "47c-5e854867d9c6.nl.audio", 
"5e854867d9c6.en.value", "92bd-91b8f180bd3a.nl.value", "4-92bd-91b8f180bd3a.en.value", 
"40a8-88ef-5890ecbOca14.nl.value", "890ecbOca14.nl.audio", "ca14.en.value"
), V2 = c("\tnstraat.", "\t1645805605.mp3", "\tconstraat.", "\tlemons", 
" \t", "\ttihdhis.", "\t645805622.mp3", "\tuse.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: sorry, what is V1 and V2? are those the columns?

Comment: Yes. columnnames you can change as you like. I will add data.

Comment: @Tarje this works well. except the .mp3 is actually a link sometimes. like `https://jds.23.mp3` and the link part gets cut off and only the numbers show up at the end. but this is perfect otherwise

Comment: I will clear that.

Comment: Replace the `B = str_extract(V2, '\\d+.mp3'),` with `B = str_extract(V2, '.*.mp3$'),`

Answer (score 1):

We may need `grep` to find the index.  Then add and subtract 1 to the index and extract the values from the second column based on that index (assuming `data.frame` columns)

```
i1 <- grep("nl.audio", df1[[1]],  fixed = TRUE)
prev_ind <- i1-1
next_ind <- i1 + 1

data.frame(col1 = df1[[2]][prev_ind], 
           col2 = df1[[2]][next_ind], 
           col3 = df1[[2]][next_ind + 1])
```